# while loop w/ 2 conditions does not work c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm working on a minigame in C++ lately. The goal is to write a little game where you have to guesse a number. If you do so you'll get a point (I call it hit there) and if you don't you'll get a "miss". Logically speaking I don't want the game to go for ever. So I was trying to use a while loop to define at which scores you can still play. How you will be able to see in the code there are two conditions. Here is why I asked you: As long as there are two conditions it just ignores these so the game turns into an endless game. I don't recive any error-messages from VS2019. When I only try it w/ one condition it works just fine.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcom to the Hit-or-Miss-minigame. Here are the rules:" << endl;
    cout << "You have to guess the same number as the computer. The numbers are within 0 and 10(both are still included)." << endl;
    cout << "If you do so, you'll get a 'HIT' but if you don't you'll get a 'MISS'. When you reach 10 'HIT's you win" << endl;
    cout << "but if you get a 'MISS' 15 times you'll lose." << endl;
    char rep = 'y';
    while (rep == 'y')
    {
        int hits = 0;
        int miss = 0;
        while ((hits < 3||miss < 15))  //Somehow doesn't work. So why?
        {
            int input_number;
            srand(time(NULL));
            int random_number = rand() % 11;
            cout << "Your number: ";
            cin >> input_number;
            if (input_number == random_number)
            {
                cout << "HIT" << endl;
                hits += 1;
            }
            else if (input_number != random_number)
            {
                cout << "MISS" << endl;
                miss += 1;
            }
            else if ((input_number > 10) || (input_number < 0))
            {
                cout << "That was not an option";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "That's not supposed to happen." << endl;
            }
        }
        if (hits == 10)
        {
            cout << "You've won! Do you want to  play another round?(y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> rep;
        }
        else if (miss == 15)
        {
            cout << "You lose! Do you want to play another round?(y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> rep;
        }
    }
}
```

I really would appreciate any help. Thanks!

EDIT: Problem solved. THANK YOU GUYS!

Comment: If you want to know how to derive something like this, you start with plain English: "I want my loop to exit if hits >= 3 or misses >= 15". Then you take the opposite of this logical statement to determine when to stay in the loop: "I want my loop to not exit (continue) if not (hits >= 3 or misses >= 15)". At this point you're done. You can make your loop condition `while (!(hits >= 3 || misses >= 15))`. If you want to simplify it further you can use DeMorgan's Law to distribute the logical "not": `while (hits < 3 && misses < 15)`

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but that call to `srand` should be **before** the loop, not inside it. Call `srand` **only once**, when the program starts.

Comment: @Pete Becker I tried this but then the random number will only be created once. This would be pretty boring because then you only would have to find out the number once to win so it would be pretty boring but still thanks for your feedback.

Comment: No, you get a new number each time you call `rand()`. Keep that inside the loop. Move the call to `srand()` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want the game will end after 3 hits or 15 misses you should use the `&&` operator and not the `||` operator

it is because the `||` operator will return `true` when **at least one** of the conditions true, the `&&` operator will return `true` when **both** of the `true`

Comment: But then it is `hits && misses`, right? So, probably, it is `||` instead :-)

Comment: @RockOGOlic with `||` the while loop will run until **both** of the conditions will be `false`, with `&&` until **one** of the conditions `false`. if he needs the misses and the hits will be over any n & m he needs to use `||`

Comment: @asaklein So just to check if I understood it right: the or-operator( `||`) will only end the while loop when both are false?

Comment: @Hunterplayer100 exactly

Answer (score 2):

Like the other comment said you should use `&&` in your while loop, because you can have 16 misses and 3 hits before the loop breaks(for example `2 < 3 || 25 < 15` returns true and is only false when you get `3 < 3 || 25 < 15`), which won't enter any if below the while, and it will just reset the variables back to 0 (this makes the while infinite). Furthermore if you put `&&` in the while you need to change the if statement for hits to `hits == 3` or it will never happen.

Also as a side note your if statement for numbers below zero and bigger than 10 needs to be above the one where you check if the guessed number is a miss (because every number bigger than 10 and smaller than 0 is a miss).
Hope this helps